# Why do I keep getting "Cannot find module 'socket.io'"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have been trying to use socket.io in my NodeJS script, but I'm constantly getting the error "Cannot find module 'socket.io'".

Full error:

```
$ sudo node /var/www/apache/server/serverScript.js
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/apache/server/serverScript.js:59:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I've tried installing socket.io globally, I've updated everything npm related, and tried all other common suggestions I found online, but the error hasn't changed.

If I had to guess, I think it's related to the package.json file. I started off with NodeJS just recently, and never used a package.json file. I saw somebody mention it as a fix, so I added one through `npm init`. This placed it in `/home/pi`. Since this didn't help, I moved the file to the js file location: `/var/www/apache/server`. Unfortunately, no luck.

Can anyone tell me what's causing this issue?

Comment: 1) Running a js server inside an Apache server makes no sense at all. 2) you have to install socket.io properly in the local node_modules.

Comment: 1) Just because it's in an Apache folder, doesn't mean it's inside an Apache server. Apache runs my webpage, NodeJS runs alongside it. There's probably better ways to do it, but this is how I've got it set up at the moment, and it works fine for me. 2) How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to give a good answer without any of your source code. However, you can try do to this.

1. Open your cmd or terminal.
2. `cd` into your project folder.
3. Run the command: `npm i --save socket.io`
4. Within your source code, type `const io = require('socket.io');` to import socket.io.

Comment: I think you may be on to something on step 2. Until now, everything I tried happened in `/home/pi`.  There's a folder there called `node_modules`, containing many modules, including `socket.io`. When I run step 3 though, I get warnings saying "no such file, open '/var/www/apache/package.json'. Any tips?

Comment: Yes, you were on to something. I `cd`'ed into the project folder, installed socket.io there and created a package.json file, and now the script does run without any errors.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no experience with having a package.json in the apache folder. but I'm happy that the script runs now! I guess the problem was that your node.js project did not have the socket.io package installed locally.

Answer (score 0):

Have you place this code at the bottom of your render document (like index.html for example) ?

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

You can just install socket IO inside your project not globally.

Comment: I haven't, no. I don't think I got that far along in the process yet, since my NodeJS file won't even run when I try to import socket.io. Could the lack of the above code result in the module not being found on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in NodeJS, you need to add the package library to your package.json. This can be done by doing:

```
npm install --save socket.io
```

**Note:** If your npm install fails to install socket.io, try to:

- Install node-gyp globally: `npm install -g node-gyp`
- Create a .npmrc file with this in the content: @types:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/

which is going to add this line to your package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "debug": "~3.1.0",
    ...    
    "socket.io-adapter": "~1.1.0",
    "socket.io-client": "2.1.1",
    "socket.io-parser": "~3.2.0"
},
```

**Note:** the dots are other packages library that may exists in there.

Then, you can use it in your code:

```
const io = require('socket.io');
```